# sort a javascript object by key : '10' is before '05'

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm using the following function to sort an object by keys.

The problem is when I have to sort '05' and '10', the '10' is sorted before the '05'

```js
function sortObj(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).sort().reduce(function(result, key) {
    result[key] = obj[key];
    return result;
  }, {});
}

let list = {
  '10': "Ann",
  '05': 75
};
let arr = sortObj(list);
console.log(arr);
```

> Object { "10": 75, "05": "Ann" }

Comment: the sorting is correct with `list = { '10_':"Ann", '05_':75 };`

Comment: Why do you want to sort an object? It makes absolutley no sense. It makes sense to sort an array, but not an object. Also your result `arr` is not an array, its still an object

Answer (score 0):

Javascript objects are not ordered by insertion order. To demonstrate, change `.sort()` to `.reverse()`

[Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Seems like you can use a map:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared

Answer (score 0):

Ordering an object makes little sense, because objects don't concern itself about the order it is as you access it's values by a key.

Though you can store your data in a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which has a key-value structure that honors it's order of insertion.

```js
function sortObj(obj) {
  return new Map(
    Object.entries(obj).sort(([a], [b]) => {
      return a - b;
    })
  );
}

let list = {
  '11': 'Beth',
  '10': "Ann",
  '05': 75,
  '07': true
};

let map = sortObj(list);
for (const [key, value] of map) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```